# how to wrap all min contours into a box or circle and find the center?

Tags: python, opencv, game-automation

i want to wrap all min contours into a box or circle and find the center.
I want to click it, but I have a problem that after the automatic click is active, it will click everything marked cv2.minEnclosingCircle. i just want to click it once using pydirectinput.
here the script

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pyautogui as py
from PIL import ImageGrab
import pydirectinput as py
import time
import win32gui, win32ui, win32con
import keyboard

def detection():
    global key,cap
    cap = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(-8,0,1194,715))
    arays = np.array(cap)
    a = cv.cvtColor(arays, cv.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
    low = np.array([100,137,175])
    up = np.array([179,255,199])
    rangeFind = cv.inRange(a, low,up)
    hq,thres = cv.threshold(rangeFind,200,255,cv.THRESH_BINARY)
    findsContours,_ = cv.findContours(thres, cv.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
    for cnt in findsContours:
        area = cv.contourArea(cnt)
        if len(cnt) > 1:
            (x,y),radius = cv.minEnclosingCircle(cnt[0])
            coord = [0,0]
            coord[0] = int(x)
            coord[1] = int(y)
            center = (int(x),int(y))
            radius = int(radius)
            cv.circle(a, center, radius, (255, 0, 0), 3)

    cv.namedWindow("hasil",cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
    cv.resizeWindow("hasil",600,400)
    
    cv.imshow("hasil",a)
    key = cv.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
while True:
    detection()  
    if key == ord("q"):
        break  
cap.release()
cv.destroyAllWindows()
```

end here the result:

[image: 1]